# How do I use pywintypes.Unicode()?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, unicode

How do I use `pywintypes.Unicode` in Python 3.3.5?

```
import pywintypes
pywintypes.Unicode("s")
```

This produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    pywintypes.Unicode("s")
TypeError: must be impossible<bad format char>, not str
```

I've [seen](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/VKjxSAjxaDY) other [code](http://nullege.com/codes/search/pywintypes.Unicode) uses that [look](https://github.com/kennethreitz-archive/pyinstaller/blob/master/versionInfo.py#L134) the same to me, so what is wrong here?

Comment: I couldn't find much documentation about pywintypes. It seems quite old?

Comment: I couldn't find either, and pywintypes seems to be implemented in C, making it a bit more opaque. However, there is code out there using it.

Comment: If you use `help(pywintypes.Unicode)` in an interactive session (or just `pywintypes.Unicode?` in IPython), do you get any documentation that way?

Comment: Not really, it just prints: ```Help on built-in function Unicode in module pywintypes:

Unicode(...)```

Comment: That's rather useless. :(

Comment: The error message you got is not very helpful, but when I googled it, it seems to have something to do with type casting. What if you try to pass a byte array instead? `pywintypes.Unicode(b's')`

Comment: I've already tried giving it bytes('s', 'utf8') and utf16. Didn't work. The thing is, I have existing code in PyInstaller which just fails because of this, and it is not from me... So it looks like it's some bug or incompatibility in the pywintypes implementation.

Comment: PyWin32's [setup.py](http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/file/713ac73c22e5/setup.py#l1526) shows that the module definition is in [win32/src/PyWinTypesmodule.cpp](http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/file/713ac73c22e5/win32/src/PyWinTypesmodule.cpp#l351), which defines `Unicode` to call `PyWin_NewUnicode`. This parses the argument as `t#` (read-only character buffer) and decodes it via `PyUnicode_DecodeMBCS`. The `'mbcs'` codec is the Windows ANSI codepage, such as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: Probably any code that needs `pywintypes.Unicode` is doing it wrong, since PyWin32 automatically handles Python strings in arguments. Python 3 strings are Unicode, so there's no reason to muck around with the mbcs codec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It's a bug affecting Python 3, and you don't need `pywintypes.Unicode(text)` in Python 3. Just use `text` directly if you need a string and `bytes(text, encoding)` if you need them as bytes.

The error

```
TypeError: must be impossible<bad format char>, not str
```

hints at the *bad format char* in the C++ source, `t#`, which is *impossible* (unknown).

Thanks to [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun)'s comments and by looking at the documentation pages of `PyArg_ParseTuple()` for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html), it becomes clear that the bug is in [win32/src/PyWinTypesmodule.cpp](http://pywin32.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/pywin32/pywin32/file/713ac73c22e5/win32/src/PyWinTypesmodule.cpp#l356).

```
PYWINTYPES_EXPORT PyObject *PyWin_NewUnicode(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    char *string;
    int slen;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "t#", &string, &slen)) // <-- BUG: Python 2 format char
        return NULL;
    return PyUnicode_DecodeMBCS(string, slen, NULL);
}
```

`t#` only exists for Python 2, for Python 3 it should be something like `s*`, and according to eryksun, MBCS-decoding is unnecessary as Python already handles Unicode strings automatically.

Comment: Did you report the bug?

Comment: Yup, reported it on sourceforge.